# BeautifulSoup is returning empty data from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am running this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'

}

r = requests.get('https://www.bohus.no/spiseplassen/oppbevaring-1/gradino-vitrine-2')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')


print(soup.find('div', class_='price').text)
```

I am trying to get the price of the product on this site: https://www.bohus.no/spiseplassen/oppbevaring-1/gradino-vitrine-2
All I am getting is empty data when running my code. Am I doing something wrong or does the website do something special to stop me from scaping price?

Comment: The contents of that div are set via javascript. Try navigating to the page using your browser with javascript turned off. Neither the `requests` module nor `BeautifulSoup` execute javascript.

Comment: A quick look at DevTools shows the page making a request to https://www.bohus.no/lite.cgi/module/priceAndStock and getting a JSON response with the price (among other things) information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can get the product data from the store's API.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"

}

product_url = "https://www.bohus.no/spiseplassen/oppbevaring-1/gradino-vitrine-2"
page_content = requests.get(product_url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'lxml')
product_id = soup.find("input", {"name": "d-session-product"})["value"]

payload = {
    "debug": "off",
    "ajax": "1",
    "product_list": product_id,
    "action": "init",
    "showStockStatusAndShoppingcart": "1",
    "enablePickupAtNearbyStores": "yes",
}

endpoint = "https://www.bohus.no/lite.cgi/module/priceAndStock"
product_data = requests.post(endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers).json()
print(product_data["price"][0]["salesPriceNormal"])
```

Output:

```
8799
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use [requests-HTML](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests_html


from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()


r = session.get('https://www.bohus.no/spiseplassen/oppbevaring-1/gradino-vitrine-2')
r.html.render()
sel='div.price-data > div.price'
print(r.html.find(sel, first=True).text)
```